# Passing data from DB to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have database which has site_url column, and created_at column such as

```
id  url  created_at
1   foo  2015-12-21
2   bar  2015-12-23
3   foo  2015-12-24
4   baz  2015-12-25
5   bar  2015-12-26
```

And I want to pass these data to view so that I can display when url is created by each url.

For now, I extracted data as follows

```
site = Model.all
each_site = site.group_by(&:url)
```

By doing this, I got a hash such as

```
{"foo" => [id: 1, url: "foo", created_at: "2015-12-21"], "bar" =>[…]}
```

Am I in the right track?

In the end, I want to do in a view like

```
foo: 2015-12-21, 2015-12-24
bar: 2015-12-23, 2015-12-26
baz: 2015-12-25
```

How can I pass the data to achieve this?

Comment: Define "having trouble with the rest".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<% site.group_by(&:url).each do |url, rest| %>
   <%= "#{url}: #{rest.map{|x| x[:created_at]}.join(', ')}" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works.
When I pass "created_at", I want to show like 2015/12/21 08:53 in the view.
Normally, I would do like 

`created_at.in_time_zone('Tokyo').strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")`

But how can I apply those method into this?

Comment: @Suda : `#{rest.map{|x| x[:created_at].in_time_zone('Tokyo').strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')}.join(', ')}" ` will work for you